# Using fseek resulting in my filepointer jumping towards EOF

Tags: c, file, eof, fseek, ftell

I'm trying to read one line from a file and go back to the start of the just read line:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\F2BJROP1.phn", "r+");
while(1){
    /**Data reading**/
    fscanf(fp, "%f", &temp1);
    if(feof(fp))
        break;
    if(isvoiced(temp1)==1){ /** isvoiced() has nothing to do with this fp. **/
        pos = ftell(fp);
        voicedIntervs[k++] = temp1;
        fscanf(fp, "%f", &temp1);
        voicedIntervs[k++] = temp1;
        fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET); /** Trying to go back to pos **/
    }
}
```

But just after the fseek, I observe that fp jumps towards the EOF. I want my fp to be back to the position stored in pos.
No other fp is declared anywhere in the program.

I know fp reaches EOF because I debugged and saw the value.

I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: You would do better testing the return value from `fscanf` (the number of items successfully read) than using `feof`. You didn't check the next use `fscanf` either ... bad!

Comment: @Weather Vane :Allright, but my requirement was that fseek should reposition the filepointer back in the position stored in variable fp

Comment: I see you just edited your code. So it's not your code. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried.

Comment: This is the minimal code. I was using 2 fscanfs and the other one just reads a character buffer which goes inside the if condition. I removed that fscanf for clarity so I had to modify the code displayed. And yeah, its my code only.

Comment: Yeah, but we have no idea what or no UB is from `isvoiced(temp1)` which you claim has nothing to do with it. If so, patch that out and prove there is still a problem. Please read the guide lines I linked. The snippet is neither complete not verifiable.

Comment: Without a [mcve], we're unable to help. Your move.

Comment: Please, add the line opening the file (the call to fopen), and state your operational system.

Comment: @jsbueno : The file was not in .txt  and was in UNIX format. Changed that and now fseek has no problems. Your comment saved me man. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Did you open your file with append mode (`a` or `a+`), as in the code below?

```
fopen(fp, "a")`
```

[Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) states that append mode does not accept repositioning:

> **append**: Open file for output at the end of a file. Output operations
>   always write data at the end of the file, expanding it. Repositioning
>   operations (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) are ignored. The file is created
>   if it does not exist.

If you did that, I suggest you try opening it with read - `r` - or read/update - `r+` - mode, as in:

```
fopen(fp, "r")`
```

Comment: Then, maybe it is reaching `EOF` at the first fscanf. Perhaps adding some `printf`s or debugging would help.

Comment: I did that. The ftell() returned a position -372, and after the fscanf() below, fp is at -368. But just after fseek(), fp reaches 2787.

Comment: Is it a big file? I meant for you to use the `printf`'s to view how much and what is read by fscanf. Is the behavior correct? Is `k` within the boundaries of `voicedIntervs`?

Comment: @AnandPA 1) If it returns a negative value, is `errno` set to an IO specific error code? 2) Also, what type is `pos`? 3) Is the file bigger than 2GB?

Comment: I saw the variables getting modified in the variable watch window of my debugger and they were totally fine and I observed expected values only. The only thing unexpected is fseek() not positioning fp back to -372.

Comment: @Koshinae: The file is just over 2500 bytes. pos is of type long. And I didn't get the need for error checking when pos is negative - whatever pos is, doesn't fseek() just put the file pointer back to that value?

Comment: @AnandPA: It should put the file position back to that value, indeed. But something else is causing `fseek` to fail. Maybe that problem is invisible to your results, but it is still causing `fseek` to misbehave. I advise you to debug your code carefully (either by printing or by debugging) and check each file repositioning and reading you are making.

Comment: Got it. The file opened was is UNIX format. I changed it to Windows format in Notepad++ and more importantly, renamed its extention to .txt. Yeah, I should've done that 3 hours before. Anyway, thanks!!